# HTML/CSS table: how to make zero border for all the cells?

Tags: html, css, border, margin, padding

I would like to create an HTML table whose cells are filled with images (say this [red square](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aui7all585ip4u5/red.png?dl=1)), and I do not want any padding/border/margin between cells.

My HTML is like below:

```
<table>
  <tr>  <td><img src="red.png"></td> <td><img src="red.png"></td>  </tr>
  <tr>  <td><img src="red.png"></td> <td><img src="red.png"></td>  </tr>
  <tr>  <td><img src="red.png"></td> <td><img src="red.png"></td>  </tr>
</table>
```

And my CSS code is

```
table {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
tr {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
td {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

However, it only collapse the horizontal border, but not vertical ones, and the result rendering is as below, and I expect a large 3x2 red square.

[image: zero-border]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Add border-collapse:collapse; in table style of CSS